# issue in division with double values

Tags: c++

why "2=" output is giving surprise results, please throw some light. what is the problem with double in this case.

any constraints for the division of double values.

Are there any options to avoid such things in c++.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<iomanip.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    double d1,d2,d3,d4,d5;
double d = 0.010000;

d1 = 1000000.28;
d2 = 10000000.28;
d3 = 100000000.28;
d4 = 1000000000.28;
d5 = 10000000000.28;

cout.precision(15);

cout<<"1="<<floor(d1/d)<<endl;
cout<<"2="<<floor(d2/d)<<endl;
cout<<"3="<<floor(d3/d)<<endl;
cout<<"4="<<floor(d4/d)<<endl;
cout<<"5="<<floor(d5/d)<<endl;

return 0;
  }

 o/p
 ====
1 = 1000000.28;
2 = 10000000.27;
3 = 100000000.28;
4 = 1000000000.28;
5 = 10000000000.28;
```

Comment: First, make a pot of coffee, then read [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). It will change what you think about floating point numbers in C/C++.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code (other than the non-standard includes), it's your assumptions that are wrong. Computers handle integers and floating-point numbers, not real numbers.

Comment: You need to use a decimal data type rather than a binary data type.

Comment: Floating point numbers are special. I find this series of articles enlightening: http://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: How do you know that a decimal data type will suffice for all values the OP wants to use? Decimal does not fix the problem if `d` is set to values such as .07.

Comment: @Eric I don't know what you are getting at. I do know that floating arithmetic with exactly representable values is exact. And to make all the values in this question exact, you need to use decimal rather than binary representation. I wonder what you feel is special about `0.07`. That can be exactly represented in decimal floating point.

Comment: @DavidHeffeman: Floating-point arithmetic with exactly representable values is generally not exact. E.g., both 1 and 3 are exactly representable in both binary and decimal, but 1/3 is not exactly representable in either. If `d` were .07. then `d2/d` is not exact. The problem is that the values in this question are just examples; we do not know what the entire set of values to be used in the software is, so we cannot know that decimal suffices to calculate correct results.

Answer (score 7):

First, the output from your program is different from what you wrote in your question. The output is:

```
1=100000028
2=1000000027
3=10000000028
4=100000000028
5=1000000000028
```

not:

```
1 = 1000000.28;
2 = 10000000.27;
3 = 100000000.28;
4 = 1000000000.28;
5 = 10000000000.28;
```

Second, when you write `double d = 0.010000`, `d` is not set to .01. It is set to a close value that is representable as a `double`. (In a good C++ implementation, it is set to the closest representable value.) In your C++ implementation, `double` is most likely an IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating-point value, and the closest representable value to .01 is 0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375.

Similarly, when you write `d2 = 10000000.28`, d2 is not set to 10000000.28. The closest representable value is 10000000.27999999932944774627685546875.

When you divide these, you get a number that is approximately, but slightly less than, 1000000028. The result of the division, rounded to a `double`, is 1000000027.99999988079071044921875. When you take the `floor` of that, the fraction is truncated, leaving 1000000027.

Avoiding or dealing with these issues requires knowledge about floating-point arithmetic and about the specific calculations you want to perform. In this case, we would need to know why you want to use `floor`.

Comment: yes output is copied incorrectly..thanks for the explanations. Actual output is as below. 1=100000028
2=1000000027
3=10000000028
4=100000000028
5=1000000000028

Comment: Good answer. Just to reiterate, it is important to remember that float/double can exactly store integral values (up to 2^24 for float, 2^53 for double) but cannot exactly store most non-integral values.

0.5 and 0.125 can be stored exactly, but 0.2 cannot be. It's for the same reason that 1/3 cannot be represented exactly in decimal, but modified because float/double are base two instead of base ten.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is um, complicated, as indicated by the comment by WhozCraig and the document he linked to.

The briefest answer I can give is to think of floating point numbers as very close approximations to the decimal counterparts (which c++ does not have the decimal data type).

A much easier way to understand this is through a great video by Jon Skeet at http://tekpub.com/blogs/video-releases/7964989-mastering-c-4-0-with-jon-skeet-7-decimals-and-floating-points.  It is WELL worth the price of admission for the clarity.  This video is specific to c# but the concepts are the same.  I never knew this problem existed before watching the video.